# Help with the birthday probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Say there are lottery tickets with three numbers. Each number has $100$ possibilities. There are $N$ tickets sold where $N > 1000$. I've tried

$$\frac{1 − 100!}{(100 − N)! 100^N}$$ 
                      and
$$\frac{1 − 300!}{(300 − N)! 300^N}$$
and they both come out to zero. 
I'm trying to calculate the probability that two or more people had the same three numbers on their lottery ticket.

Is this correct or should it be a greater number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(100-N)!$ doesn't make a whole lot of sense when $N>100$ in this context...

P(multiple the same)=1-P(all different)=1-(# of ways to choose N unique items from a collection of $3^{100}$)/($3^{100}$)
$$1-\frac{{3^{100}\choose N}}{3^{100}}=1-\frac{3^{99}!}{(3^{100}-N)!(N!)}$$

Comment: That's what I thought, but I think that's the formula the professor wanted us to use...

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Just added that to the question. :)

Comment: I think you mean "the probability that" not "if"

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'll change it again.

Comment: Edited with answer.

Comment: Is the three because of the three numbers on the ticket?

Comment: 3 numbers on the ticket each with 100 choices.